# How to calculate the gradient in cylindrical coordinates in more efficient way?

Tags: equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, vector-calculus

I would like to obtain the gradient for  the following function  in cylindrical Coordinates

```
f[r, \[Theta], z]= BesselJ[0, r Sqrt[\[Omega]^2/c^2 - Subscript[k, z]^2] ] S[Subscript[
   k, z]] Exp[ I Subscript[k, z] z]   

Grad[f[r, \[Theta], z], {r, \[Theta], z}, "Cylindrical"]
```

The output is given in terms of  Subscript (interpreted as derivates), it is possible to do more readable.  How can define the function S(k_ z) to use for depended and independent of z?

Comment: `f[r_, \[Theta]_, z_] := 
 BesselJ[0, r Sqrt[\[Omega]^2/c^2 - Subscript[k, z]^2]] S[
   Subscript[k, z]] Exp[I Subscript[k, z] z]`

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear if $k_z$ depends on z or not. In both cases, you can try writing in the following way:

```
f[r_, \[Theta]_, z_] := 
 BesselJ[0, r Sqrt[\[Omega]^2/c^2 - k[z]^2]] S[k[z]] Exp[I k[z] z];
Grad[f[r, \[Theta], z], {r, \[Theta], z}, "Cylindrical"]
```

with $k[z]$ taking into account for the dependance.

The output is the gradient in cylindrical coordinates

```
{-E^(I k z) BesselJ[1, r Sqrt[\[Omega]^2/9 - k[z]^2]] Sqrt[\[Omega]^2/9 - k[z]^2]S[k[z]],
 0, 
 (E^(I z k[z])
   r BesselJ[1, r Sqrt[\[Omega]^2/9 - k[z]^2]] k[z] S[k[z]]
 Derivative[1][k][z])/Sqrt[\[Omega]^2/9 - k[z]^2] + BesselJ[0, r Sqrt[\[Omega]^2/9-k[z]^2]]
 S[k[z]] (I k[z] + I z Derivative[1][k][z]) + 
 E^(I z k[z]) BesselJ[0, r Sqrt[\[Omega]^2/9 - k[z]^2]] Derivative[1][k][z] Derivative[1][S][k[z]]}
```

and it is quite complicated because k depends on z. If k does not depend on z, the output is:

```
{-E^(I k z) BesselJ[1, r Sqrt[\[Omega]^2/9 - k^2]] Sqrt[\[Omega]^2/9 - k^2] S[k],
 0, 
 I E^(I k z) k BesselJ[0, r Sqrt[\[Omega]^2/9 - k^2]] S[k]}
```